# Есть ли разница в расположении операндов в выражении php?

Tags: php

Существует ли разница (если есть то в чем) между такими выражениями?
`if ($a === null) {}` и `if (null === $a) {}`
`if ($a > 1) {}` и `if (1 < $a) {}`

И другими подобными...

Comment: разница может существовать, когда операндами являются функции, в этом случае сначала будет вызвана одна, потом другая, а потом результаты будет сравнены. в случае простых типов данных разницы никакой

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В приведенных примерах разницы никакой. В тоже время у некоторых программистов сложилась практика ставить на первое место константу, если такое возможно.
Например:

```
if (1 == $a) {}
```

Это связано с тем, что исключает возможные ошибки при написании кода. Бывает так, что программист хотел сравнить

```
if ($a == 1) {}
```

Но по ошибке написал

```
if ($a = 1) {}
```

Что приведет к тому, что данное условие всегда будет истинным. 
Именно поэтому чтобы избежать подобных ошибок, предпочитают на первое место поставить константу, что не позволит использовать оператор присваивания.

Comment: константы порой выносят вперед и в языках, где присваивания не такие (например, паскаль), особенно когда выражение длинное (функция  с несколькими параметрами и т.п.) с тем чтобы сразу было видно с чем сравнивается.